# jQuery, function is not defined, only on IE<9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, function

I have this in jQuery:

```
$(function(){ 

function updateList(){ 
    //HERE MY FUNCTION
}

});
```

And :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateList();
});
```

they are on the same file. When i load my page, i have `ReferenceError: updateList is not defined`.

On Firefox and ie9 it's ok....

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Edit : And bonus question, this code doesn't work on IE<9 :

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "rechercheArtisan_ajax.html?action=metier&IDmetier="+secteur_activite, 
dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
success: function( data ) {
var xml;
if (typeof data == "string") {
xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xml.async = false;
xml.loadXML(data);
} else {
xml = data;
}
// Returned data available in object "xml"
if ( $(xml).is("erreur") )
{
alert( "Erreur : " + $(xml).find("erreur").text() );
}
else
{
$("#id_metier").attr("disabled", "");
updateList( "metier" , $(xml).find("list") );
}
}
});
```

No error, nothing, just no effect.

Comment: `$(function() { });` and `$(document).ready(function() { });` do the same thing. Try putting your `updateList()` function call in the same wrapper.

Comment: The scope of the `updateList` is inside `$(function(){ });`. It shouldn't be fine in any browser. Anyways, why do you need 2 different ready handler? You could just do it one handler.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DQnsK/ -- I believe is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of the `updateList` is inside `$(function(){ });`. It shouldn't be fine in any browser.

Why do you need 2 different ready handler?

Either move the function outside document ready like below,

```
<script>
function updateList () { }

$(function () {
   updateList();
});
</script>
```

or Just use one ready handler function.

```
<script>   
$(function () {
   function updateList () { }

   //some other code

   updateList();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks... it's just that.. ^^ And bonus question, i edit my post ;)

Comment: @ClémentAndraud You should post a new question for your bonus question.

Comment: If you have another question, please post it as a separate question.